# Really vague Regex question: string that always iterates between uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: python, regex

I am stuck at a regEx problem that says "Make a regex that matches a string of 10 characters that always iterate between uppercase and lowercase letters."
The question is from a online quiz kind of thing, and when you input your response it tells you whether it is right or wrong.
I have tried a bunch of options but none of them work, as the question is a bit blurry for me.

`([a-z][A-Z]){5}`

`([a-z][A-Z]){5}|([A-Z][a-z]){5}`

According to me, I believe that the question simply wants us to match strings like 
`AaAaAaAaAa` or `aAaAaAaAaA`

Comment: How do you conclude that your latter attempt is wrong? What do you think is blurry about the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the code you need to incorporate this regexp in and id it suppose to get exactly 10 characters, but you are probably in the right direction. I think you can use this:

```
\b(?:[a-z][A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z]){5}\b
```

see online: https://regex101.com/r/bynUwn/1

Answer (score 0):

Your current pattern matches a repetition of 5 times 2 characters but has no specific boundaries. What you might do is use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b([A-Z][a-z]){5}\b`

Another option could be to use anchors to assert the start and the end of the string and use a positive lookahead to assert the length of the string to 10:

```
^(?=.{10}$)[A-Z]?(?:[a-z][A-Z])+[a-z]?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?=[a-zA-Z]{10}$)` Assert lenght of 10 characters a-z
- `[A-Z]?` Match optional uppercase char
- `(?:[a-z][A-Z])+` Match 1+ times a lowercase char followed by an uppercase char
- `[a-z]?` Match optional lowercase char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0EmRe/1)